# print ArrayList that contains StringBuffer objects

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, stringbuffer

I have an `ArrayList`, that stores objects of `StringBuffer` class.
Now I want to print that `ArrayList`. How could I do that.

```
Iterator itr=al.iterator(); 
while(itr.hasNext())
{  
    System.out.println(itr.next()); 
}
```

This just prints the last object for `al.size` times.
Also if you could please tell me why it only prints the last object's value

Comment: Wild guess, the list contains the same `StringBuffer` instance. You should show us more code

Comment: It should work. No changes needed.

Comment: For that matter, `ArrayList` has a well-behaved `toString`, and I'd just use `System.out.println(al)`.

Comment: please show us how you fill your array list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(new StringBuffer("keshav"));
        al.add(new StringBuffer("sharma"));

        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

    }

}
```

Its working fine for me.

output:

```
keshav
sharma
```

Comment: thank you Keshav Sharma, that worked. I was actually not creating a new StringBuffer object when adding to arraylist.